# Como deixar novo form sem depender do outro?

Tags: c#, winforms

Aqui o código que faz abrir meu Form4:

```
Form4 form4 = new Form4();
form4.Show();
// Aqui um código gigantesco que demora aproximadamente 1 minuto para ser executado.
form4.Close();
```

O problema é que enquanto o Form4 está aberto, ele fica meio cinza e estático, não da pra mover ele e nem fechar. Eu entendo que ele fica meio dependente do código do form anterior, como resolver isso?

Comment: de mais detalhes dos erros, das exceptions

Comment: Não tem exceção nenhuma.

Comment: o close termina a execução do aplicativo. se vc quer fechar o form sem fechar o app, Hide no lugar de Close

Comment: Tem que correr o seu código noutra thread, ou de forma assincrona, para não bloquear a thread de UI. Existem varias fromas de fazer isso. Experimente por exemplo meter o "codigo gigantesco". dentro de um `ThreadPool.QueueUserItem`. Se der mais detalhes da sua pergunta avise, que eu formularei uma resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, de uma olhada em: [Processamentos longos...](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158589/winforms-c-exibir-formul%C3%A1rio-de-carregamento/158758#158758)

Lá tem uma resposta postada por mim e acredito que seja uma solução para você.
Basicamente você precisa iniciar este segundo form em uma Thread diferente da que executa o processamento principal, assim os forms ficam independentes e quando um processamento longo for executado o outro form não ficara congelado.

Abraços!