# WinForms C# - Exibir formulário de carregamento

Tags: c#, winforms, async

Possuo um WinForms principal e gostaria que enquanto a tarefa assíncrona esteja processando, um novo formulário (com **GIF**) seja exibido, este só se fecharia ao terminar o processamento.

```
             frmProcessor _frmProcessor = new frmProcessor();
            _frmProcessor.ShowDialog(); //Este é o formulário que é exibido enquanto a tarefa é executada.

            string account = await _manager.DoAccount(email, password);
            if (account != "")
            {
                ...
            }
            else
            {
                ...
            }
            _frmProcessor.Hide(); // Então o formulário é fechado
```

Na execução o aplicativo não processa as instruções seguintes a linha de exibição do formulário:

```
_frmProcessor.ShowDialog();
```

O sistema fica parado nesse momento. Alguma maneira de contornar este problema?

Comment: amigo ele so volta executar quando o _frmProcessor e fechado. para continuar executando use .show

Comment: A execução está continuando, obrigado pela resposta. Não imaginaria que este método bloqueava a execução com o formulário principal.

Comment: Estamos aqui para nos ajudar. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O programa executou perfeitamente com a alteração do método.

```
_frmProcessor.Show();
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Olá,
Para processamentos longos...
Para que seu form auxiliar continue executando o Gif durante o processamento será preciso que você o inicie em uma Thread diferente da Thread onde será feito o processamento.

Segue o exemplo do form auxiliar onde será exibido sua imagem Gif:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Connessioni.Elos.DB.Remote.Controls
{

/// <summary>
/// Form padrão para ser exibido quando um processamento longo é iniciado
/// </summary>
public partial class FrWorking : Form
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Se o form foi iniciado
    /// </summary>
    public bool Started;

    /// <summary>
    /// Contrutor
    /// </summary>
    public FrWorking()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exibe o form como dialog
    /// </summary>
    public void ShowDiag()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the <see cref="E:System.Windows.Forms.Form.Shown"/> event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">A <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> that contains the event data. </param>
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnShown(e);
        Application.DoEvents();
        BringToFront();
        Started = true;
    }

}
```

}

Agora segue o exemplo de como utilizar este form:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Carrega a.....
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void btLoad_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //Form a ser exibido durante o processamento
        var w = new FrWorking();
        //Executando o form auxiliar em uma nova System.Threading.Thread
        var t = new Thread(w.ShowDiag);
        //Iniciando a Thread
        t.Start();

        //Aguardando até q a Thread seja iniciada
        while (!w.Started) { }

        //:) Execute seu processamento aqui, e seja feliz....

        try
        {
            //Fechando form auxiliar
            t.Abort();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: O processamento do AP já é feito de forma assincrona e por esse motivo não bloqueia a user-interface. Resumindo a sua resposta é uma alternativa pior à do AP

Comment: Estamos aqui para nos ajudar, ser gentil com o próximo também é importante Bruno.